# Как сделать чтобы позиция элемента была равна позиции "thumb" input на JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, rangeslider

Учу JS, сделал range slider, все работает более-менее. Когда ползунок на 50% тогда все ок, но когда значение больше или меньше 50%, то позиция счетчика числа, который появляется сверху, уже не равна позиции thumb. Как это исправить?

```js
const slideValue = document.querySelector("span");
const inputSlider = document.querySelector("input")

inputSlider.oninput = function () {
  const spanValue = inputSlider.value;
  slideValue.textContent = spanValue;
  slideValue.style.left = (spanValue / 5000) + "%";
  slideValue.classList.add("show");
};

inputSlider.onblur = function () {
  slideValue.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #664aff;
}

.range {
  height: 80px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 65px;
}

.range .sliderValue {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.range .sliderValue span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  top: -50px;
  line-height: 55px;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.range .sliderValue span.show {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1);
}

.range .sliderValue span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #664aff;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

.range .field {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.range .field .value {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #664aff;
}

.range .field .value.left {
  left: -7px;
}

.range .field .value.right {
  right: -50px;
}

.range .field input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.range .field input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #664aff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Range Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="range">
      <div class="sliderValue">
        <span>100</span>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <div class="value left">0</div>
        <input type="range" min="0" , max="500000" value="250000" steps="1" />
        <div class="value right">500000</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто, при расчёте позиции, нужно учитывать отступы и ширину ползунка:

```js
const slideValue = document.querySelector("span");
const inputSlider = document.querySelector("input")

inputSlider.oninput = function() {
  const spanValue = inputSlider.value;
  slideValue.textContent = spanValue;
  slideValue.style.left = `${20 + (this.clientWidth - 20) / 100 * (spanValue / 5000)}px`;
  slideValue.classList.add("show");
};

inputSlider.onblur = function() {
  slideValue.classList.remove("show");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: #664aff;
}

.range {
  height: 80px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0 65px;
}

.range .sliderValue {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.range .sliderValue span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  top: -50px;
  line-height: 55px;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.range .sliderValue span.show {
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1);
}

.range .sliderValue span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #664aff;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  left: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}

.range .field {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.range .field .value {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #664aff;
}

.range .field .value.left {
  left: -7px;
}

.range .field .value.right {
  right: -50px;
}

.range .field input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.range .field input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #664aff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Range Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="range">
    <div class="sliderValue">
      <span>100</span>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="value left">0</div>
      <input type="range" min="0" , max="500000" value="250000" steps="1" />
      <div class="value right">500000</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: |(${20 + (this.clientWidth - 20) / 100 *) - можно уточнить)|   {20 (это оступ?) + (this.clientWidth (это ширина ползунка?) - 20 (это какой-то падинг?) / 100 (и если можно, зачем делить на 100?))

Comment: @Vitaliy: первая "20-ка" - это `margin` у Вас в стилях; `this.clientWidth` - это ширина `input`; вторая "20-ка" - это диаметр кнопки у `input`.